# Vectorize this strfind loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization, string-matching, template-matching, string-math

I'm looking to vectorize this loop:

```
needle = [1 2 3];

haystack  = [0 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3;
             0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0;
             0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0];

for ii = 1:3

    indices{ii} = strfind (haystack(ii,:), needle);

end

indices{:}
```

`indices` then contains the starting positions of `needle` in each row of `haystack` (could be different number of times per row):

```
3 7
2 6
4
```

Any command(s) will do, doesn't have to be `strfind`, as long as its vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use for loop, you co do as follows:

```
 result = cellfun(@(row) strfind(row, needle), num2cell(haystack, 2), 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to concatenate the entire `haystack` variable and then find the `needle` in it as follows:

```
totalWhiteSpaces=isspace(haystack); %finds white space locations
totalWhiteSpaces=sum(totalWhiteSpaces(1,:),2); %Assumes that "haystack" has equal number 
                                     %of characters (including whitespaces) in each row.

realColumns=size(haystack,2)-totalWhiteSpaces; %gets how many characters are 
                                               %there in a row excluding whitespaces
needle(needle==' ')='';
haystack1=haystack';
haystack2=(haystack1(:))';
haystack2(haystack2==' ')='';  %removes whitespace
result=strfind(haystack2,needle);  %find the pattern
rowsOfResult=uint32(result/realColumns)+1; %necessary since we had concatenated the array.
                                          %It is kind of reshaping operation.
resultValue=mod(result,realColumns);
```

I guess you can form your final matrix from here.

Timing results: You can see the advantage of this code when your `haystack` becomes larger. According to my experiments, for a size of `300000x9` - your code takes about 0.38 seconds. My code takes about 0.23 seconds and the code using `cellfun` takes 2.23 seconds. I guess that is because of the `num2cell` operation. Also, `cellfun` uses a `for-loop` internally, so it is not truly vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept the result in a different format (more suited to vectorization):

```
[m n] = size(haystack);
haystackLin = haystack.';
haystackLin = haystackLin(:).'; %// linearize haystack row-wise
ind = strfind(haystackLin,needle); %// find matches
[jj ii] = ind2sub([n m],ind); %// convert to row and column
valid = jj<=n-numel(needle)+1; %// remove false matches (spanning several rows)
result = [ii(valid).' jj(valid).'];
```

The result format is

```
result =

     1     3
     1     7
     2     2
     2     6
     3     4
```

Comment: Luis, I don't think either of those two methods would work for "needle = [1 2 3 0 1];".

Comment: Luis, it's not about having a zero or not in 'needle'. Using any non-zero won't work either. The real issue is because of concatenation it extends into the next row. This is discussed in my code. Ok, I think you have made the change, great!

Comment: @Divakar Yes, I think we've both arrived at the same conclusion :-) Having equal elements in `needle` was also problematic with my former `conv` approach

Comment: Yeah, that was .. something :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with finding the column numbers with their corresponding row numbers in a different vector, as suggested by Luis, you may use this too -

```
%// Main portion
haystack_t = haystack';
num1 = strfind(num2str(haystack_t(:))',num2str(needle(:))');
col = rem(num1,size(haystack,2));
ind = floor(num1/size(haystack,2))+1;

%// We need to remove indices that get into account because of concatenation of all the numbers into one big string
rm_ind = col> (size(haystack,2) - numel(needle))+1;
col(rm_ind)=[];
ind(rm_ind)=[];
```

Runs with various needle inputs -

```
RUN1 (Original values):
needle =
     1     2     3
haystack =
     0     0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3
     0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3     0
     0     0     0     1     2     3     0     0     0
col =
     3     7     2     6     4
ind =
     1     1     2     2     3

RUN2 :
needle =
     1     2     3     0     1
haystack =
     0     0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3
     0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3     0
     0     0     0     1     2     3     0     0     0
col =
     3     2
ind =
     1     2
```